# how to grab only first few commits with Git bundle create

Tags: git, github, repository, bundle, gitlab

I have a git repo and I want to use the git bundle command to only grab a portion of the repo.

Lets say there are 10 commits in this repo, but I only want to grab the first 3? And maybe at a later time grab the next 3? and so on

How can I leverage the git bundle command in order to do this?

Feel free to fill in the blanks on other details I may have not provided, that could be useful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE** - incorporating info about a limitation of bundles.  tl;dr - you have to have a ref at the bundle's head

The commits to include in the bundle are specified using the same syntax you would use to specify what you want to see in a `log` command (among others), with the exception that you must use named refs (branches or tags) to indicate what should be included.  So for your example (bundle the 1st 3 commits, then later the next 3, from a repo with 10 commits):

You have a repo with

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H -- I -- J <--(master)
```

Then you say

```
git bundle create a_to_c.bundle C
```

where `C` a ref (branch or tag) pointing to `C`.  Later

```
git bundle create d_to_f.bundle C..F
```

In this case `C` may be the SHA ID for commit `C` (or an unambiguous prefix of that ID), or it may still be a re; but `F` must be a ref (tag or branch) pointing to commit `F`.

This syntax works any time you want to *include* what's reachable from one commit (`F` in this example) *except for* what's reachable from another (`C`).  An equivalent command is

```
git bundle create d_to_f.bundle ^C F
```

which shows a more general syntax wherein you can easily add multiple commits to  be included or excluded.

You note in comments that you could make this work with tags, but not SHA ID's.  What I had forgotten - but someone pointed out to me in the form of an unfortunately-unclear edit - is that a bundle cannot contain dangling commits.  Every commit in the bundle must be reachable from a ref in the bundle.  I suppose this prevents creation of dangling objects that would be difficult to access - and that would be immediately eligible for gc in any case - when applying the bundle to another repo.

Comment: When I try the commands above I get the error message: fatal: Refusing to create empty bundle.

Comment: I've tried with using the shortened hash or the hash. I can get it to work with tags, but I would like to do it without the use of tags

Comment: Updated to reflect the reason for this confusion.  Credit where due as best as possible - I'd missed this (been a long time since I used bundles) and it was pointed out to me in a proposed edit. Unfortunately that edit wasn't well-integrated into the answer so I've rewritten it myself.

Comment: So basically it can't be done using the hashes alone, I would need to use tags or bundle the entire repo with the master ref

Comment: Well, tags or branches.  You could move `master` to `C`, then move it to `F`... Keep in mind that when you apply the bundle, it's like a temporary remote.  If you're cloning it, then I guess there's a slight advantage to having the ref be a branch named `master`; but generally with the right pull syntax it doesn't matter that much.